# python win32com excel, getting a list of all available functions

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

Is there a way to get all functions? i tried even check the pywin32 source code, but even in the source code i couldnt find the implementation of lots of functions like

```
excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
```

i can't find a list of functions and variables that workbook would have, or excel itself, usually when there is no doc i can deepdive in the source code, but here i kinda got stuck,

Is there any place i could find a list of functions for the Excel and Word COM?

Comment: `pythoncom` does not provide implementations of those functions. It talks to the application's  COM server and returns VBA objects in a thin Python wrapper. The object model is documented in  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model.  This assumes you are writing in VBA. So you need to convert the syntax of the samples, as: named parameters in function calls are `:=` in VBA but `=` in Python; parameterless methods don't need parens in VBA, but in Python they do; VBA code relies heavily on named constants that you have to Google to find the values for.

Comment: @BoarGules Agree ... anyone using Excel via COM should have this link bookmarked! Also, if you use `win32com.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')` instead then these constants are generated for you, and you can refer to them in your Python code, eg `win32com.constants.xlCalculationAutomatic` gives you -4105.